# Control a bone axis using another bone

Tags: objects, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I would like to rotate the length axis of an object (or bone) that is otherwise rigidly fixed/parented to a moving second object.  I want to parent a/another bone to the second object that always points via IK to a third target object.  I'm after something like the manual motor start handle on an old Model T car or a cheap car jack, the handle effectively following the hand that turns it so as to rotate the portion that actually turns the motor or jack.  Is it even possible to do that in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be best to know what your ultimate end goal is; there are different techniques one can use, and they're ideal for different situations.

As one general kind of technique that can be used, here's a locked track:

[image]

Armatures with two different rotations of "crank" bone, to which "handle" is parented.  Handle has a locked track constraint that rotates about its (transformed) Y axis to point its +Z axis at "trackTarget" as best it can.

trackTarget can be moved up in the world Z axis as desired; at a certain distance, handle will not noticeably rotate at all.  (It would be nice if Blender could make an object infinitely distant.)  Or, trackTarget can be constrained to another object, perhaps with a child-of constraint, so that handle follows that rotation, but only in a single axis.

Simply disabling "inherit rotation" on handle may be an alternative, but in that case, it won't inherit rotation in *any* axes from its hierarchy.  A limit rotation constraint is probably how many people will first want to approach this problem, but world axes will change with the orientation of the object, and local-with-parent will bug out at times due to how Blender handles this constraint.  I try to solve my rotation problems with damped and locked track constraints instead to avoid any interpolation surprises.